# laravel: display data from a drop down list

Tags: laravel

I am implementing a drop down menu list to display a list of hotels from my system. I currently have the following code which when i click submit, nothing is happening (no data displayed).

Does anyone know how i can potentially display data once i press submit ?

Search.Blade.php

```
{!! Form::open(['action' => 'SearchController@index', 'method' => 'POST']) !!}

 <div class="form-group">

 <select name="title" id="title" class="form-control input-lg dynamic" data-dependent="state">

 @foreach($posts as $post)
    <option value="{{$post->id}}">{{$post->title}} </option>
 @endforeach

 </select>
 <br>
  <div class="form-group">
 {{Form::Submit('submit', ['class' => 'btn btn-primary'])}}
 </div>


    <div class="table">
    <table>
    <tr>
     <th>Hotel Name</th>
     <td>{{$post->title}}</td>
     <th>Distance</th>
     <td>{{$post->distance}}</td>
     <th>Images</th>
     <td>{{$post->image}}</td>
    </tr>
  <tr>
  </tr>
 </td>
    </div>
```

SearchController.php

```
  public function index()
    {
     $posts = Post::get();
     return view('Pages.search', compact('posts'));
     }
   public function store(Request $request)
  {



  }
```

So when i press submit, it takes me to a white blank page. Im not sure how to retrieve the data from the selected drop down list and display it on my page, if any one knows how to do so please advise.

Comment: This is the very basics of Laravel, you should follow a tutorial or read the online documentation: https://laravel.com/docs/6.x

Answer (score 1):

After submitting the form you will land on the `store()` page because you are firing a POST request. Your store method is empty so you will get an empty screen. Make your store method like this to start with:

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    // This will return all request data to your screen.
    return $request->all();
}
```

If you would like to stay on the index method you have to change your form method to GET. Then you only have to get the Post details from the template, since you're already sending all Posts from the index method:

```
{!! Form::open(['action' => 'SearchController@index', 'method' => 'GET']) !!}
<div class="form-group">
    <select name="title" id="title" class="form-control input-lg dynamic" data-dependent="state">
        <option value="">Choose an item</option>
        @foreach($posts as $post)
            <option value="{{ $post->id }}">{{ $post->title }}</option>
        @endforeach
    </select>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    {{ Form::Submit('submit', ['class' => 'btn btn-primary']) }}
</div>
{!! Form::close() !!}

@if(request('title') and $item = $posts->where('id', request('title')))
    <div class="table">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <th>Hotel name</th>
                <td>{{ $post->title }}</td>
                <th>Distance</th>
                <td>{{ $post->distance }}</td>
                <th>Images</th>
                <td>{{ $post->image }}</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
@endif
```

Comment: Hi this did something, not quite there yet, it returned a white blank page with : {"_token":"dJBc0ak8fGN92MuOVebdi9bWQw76AukJfU0q5Fi4","title":"3"}. This is correct as its returning the correct value (3), however how do i get it to display on my page using the updated code on search.blade.php ?

Comment: Also is it worth changing 'post' to GET as i am getting the data

Comment: Yes, if you change POST to GET you will stay on the index method and can use $request->get('title') to get your request data here. Or in your template like {{ request('title'). Depending on you purposes..

Comment: sorry just got confused with the $request->get(title) stuff, can you maybe change the code a little to see how it should look. So that it will display on my page when i press submit.

Comment: so now i have noticed that in my url it says http://fyp.test/search?title=4 so i know that it is working, however now i need to know how to display this information onto my screen.

Comment: I did change my post to answer your question. In your template you check for request('title') and if given we get the current post with a where statement on the $posts.

Comment: Hi unfortunately this did not work, i was also curious with the use of $item and how that works

Comment: Oops, use $item->title and $item->distance instead. I did search the item in $posts and save it in $item.

Answer (score 0):

Change this at Controller :

```
Post::get(); to Post::all()
```

Try this. Hopefully work for you

Answer (score 0):

If you are using [Laravel's Resourceful Controller Routing](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/controllers#resource-controllers) then the `index()` route handles `GET` requests, and the `store()` route handles `POST` requests to the same endpoint.

> Although you have your form action as `SearchController@index` it only
>   resolves to a URL which happens to be the same URL as
>   `SearchController@store` and what separates how Laravel handles them
>   is the request method as I mentioned above.

Therefore you are probably looking for something along these lines:

```
public function store(Request $request) { 
    $post = Post:: findOrFail($request->title); 
    return view('Pages.[page-name-here'], compact('post')); 
}
```

If you have any trouble understanding which route responds to the combination of endpoint and method go to your command line and use `php artisan route:list` to see the endpoint mappings for your routes.

---

> **$request->title**
>
> As used above matches the `<select name='title'>` in your blade
>   template. You may want to change them to `post` for when you come back to
>   it down the road you can understand what's going on.

---

> **findOrFail()**
>
> As used above will throw a 404 not found error and stop execution if a
>   matching Model isn't retrieved from the database with the given title.
>   You could just as well use `find()` and check for a Post model and
>   redirect back to the previous page, throw a validation failed or whatever your desired response is when a Post isn't retrieved.